# Include and then edit included android

Tags: android, include, navigation-drawer, toolbar, drawerlayout

i need to include drawer toolbar, it includes whole layout with text. But i want to the same toolbar on all activites but with different text, how should i do it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_final">
</include>
```

this is **toolbar_final.xml**
Main Layout is what i need to edit,
i need to include whole layout and get to the Linearlayout with MainLayout TextView and add my own things (buttons and stuff) into it, i hope u get what mean.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.Info">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Main Layout"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**navigation_action.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nav_action"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/toolbarTextColor"
app:title="myApp">
```

and **nav_header.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="140dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Header Text"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Comment: you mean you want to a use 1 actionbar for all activity but different title ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by setting tittle on toolbar at runtime.
Use the same toolbar in every class and in which you want to change the text , use setTitle of toolbar and set the tittle according to that class.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // get the reference of Toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTittle("Class name")
```